# Register form compatible with MVC pattern in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm wondering what is the best way to create register form which will be compatible with MVC pattern. Lets suppose that I have a View containing some text fields:

- Name
- Surname
- Email
- Password

and button to send that data to the Controller when user fills all of the TextFields.

The View conforms to protocol that should send the data from View to Controller. In this approach I am sending the object which I don't think is a good idea.

```
@objc public func acceptButtonHit(sender: UIButton){

    if checkIfTextFieldsConainsCharacters(){
        let userData = UserRegisterData()
        userData.name = nameTextField.text!
        userData.surname = surnameTextField.text!
        userData.email = emailTextField.text!
        userData.password = passwordTextField.text!
        delegate?.logInButtonAction(sender: sender, text: userData)
    }
}
```

I can use all of the data as a parameters but when I need to send more data then this approach doesn't look good.

```
@objc public func acceptButtonHit(sender: UIButton){

    if checkIfTextFieldsConainsCharacters(){

        let name = nameTextField.text!
        let surname = surnameTextField.text!
        let email = emailTextField.text!
        let password = passwordTextField.text!
        delegate?.logInButtonAction(sender: sender, name: name, surname: surname, email: email, password: password)
    }
}
```

I have a Model let it be the struct:

```
    struct UserData {
        let name:String
        let surname: String
        let email: String
        let password: String
     }
```

Controller initialize View and connects with server.

The question is what is the best way or ways to send data from the View to the Controller and update the Model. 
I will be grateful for any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you curious how to maintain this user object throughout multiple controllers? If so, employing user defaults is likely your best bet.

Comment: No, actually I want to send it to only one Controller and save it on the server. But I am curious what is the best way to do this when dealing with such problems in the future.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit as to what issues you are facing with your current implementation? What is raising concern for you, specifically?

Comment: I edited my post :)

Comment: Have you considered adding an initializer to your struct so you can initialize the entire `UserData` object in one line of code? As opposed to initializing an empty `UserData` object and adding each property on a separate line?

Comment: Sure but according to MVC pattern View cannot update Model